# TTitleBarPanel overlapping nested Panel when the main Form loses focus

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, tform

When running a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, initially it looks fine (except the Mainmenu is hidden):

[image]

But as soon as the window loses focus, the `TTitleBarPanel` OVERLAPS **pnlHeader** (which is a nested `TPanel` inside a `TCard`):

[image]

But I have done as the Documentation says: Put everything except the `TTitleBarPanel` on a client-aligned Panel.

How can this overlapping be avoided?

Here is the Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.TitleBarCtrls, Vcl.WinXPanels;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    menuitemOptions: TMenuItem;
    menuitemPreferences: TMenuItem;
    menuitemAbout: TMenuItem;
    pnlHeader: TPanel;
    TitleBarPanel1: TTitleBarPanel;
    CardPanel1: TCardPanel;
    Card1: TCard;
    Panel1: TPanel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

And here is the Form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 294
  ClientWidth = 515
  Color = clSilver
  CustomTitleBar.Control = TitleBarPanel1
  CustomTitleBar.Enabled = True
  CustomTitleBar.Height = 34
  CustomTitleBar.BackgroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ForegroundColor = 65793
  CustomTitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = 10066329
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = 65793
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = 65793
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = 16053492
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = 65793
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = 15395562
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = 10066329
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = clWhite
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  GlassFrame.Enabled = True
  GlassFrame.Top = 34
  Menu = MainMenu1
  Position = poScreenCenter
  StyleElements = [seFont, seClient]
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object TitleBarPanel1: TTitleBarPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 515
    Height = 34
    CustomButtons = <>
    ExplicitWidth = 608
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 34
    Width = 515
    Height = 260
    Align = alClient
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    TabOrder = 1
    ExplicitTop = 33
    ExplicitWidth = 608
    ExplicitHeight = 296
    object CardPanel1: TCardPanel
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 515
      Height = 260
      Align = alClient
      ActiveCard = Card1
      BevelOuter = bvNone
      Caption = 'CardPanel1'
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitTop = 34
      ExplicitWidth = 608
      ExplicitHeight = 355
      object Card1: TCard
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 515
        Height = 260
        Caption = 'Card1'
        CardIndex = 0
        DoubleBuffered = True
        ParentDoubleBuffered = False
        TabOrder = 0
        ExplicitWidth = 608
        ExplicitHeight = 355
        object pnlHeader: TPanel
          Left = 0
          Top = 0
          Width = 515
          Height = 32
          Margins.Left = 100
          Margins.Top = 0
          Margins.Right = 150
          Margins.Bottom = 0
          Align = alTop
          Alignment = taLeftJustify
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          Color = 16443110
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clGrayText
          Font.Height = -19
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = []
          ParentBackground = False
          ParentFont = False
          TabOrder = 0
          ExplicitWidth = 608
        end
      end
    end
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 320
    Top = 192
    object menuitemOptions: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Options'
      object menuitemPreferences: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Toggle Preferences'
        ShortCut = 123
      end
      object menuitemAbout: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'About'
        ShortCut = 121
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: My two cents: If you want to make a robust, non-obnoxious, performant, accessible, compatible, and future-proof application, you stay away from VCL styles and custom title bars.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But do you know a solution for this particular question?

Comment: I suspect you cannot combine a custom title bar with a Win32 menu bar.

Comment: And even if you remove the menu bar, it took me five seconds to find the second bug: You cannot right-click the title bar to obtain the system menu. Third bug: If you press Alt+Space to open the system menu and then use arrow keys and Enter to select the Move item, you don't enter the move loop; instead, the system menu repopups.

Comment: Oh, God: The fourth bug is even worse: Just pressing the Alt key (or F10) causes a stack overflow + access violation + app crash.

Comment: (I did my tests on 10.4, and I think some of these issues have been fixed in Delphi 11. Still, I wouldn't use a custom title bar -- not even a Delphi 11 one -- in an application that controls a patient's pacemaker.)

Comment: Other features a title bar must support: doubleclick maximizes/restores window, doubleclick on icon closes window. Not handling ALT or F10 is a deal breaker for handicapped people or power users.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand So you say that `TTitleBarPanel` has a lot of bugs and to not use it?

Comment: @user1580348: Sadly, yes. I would not recommend anyone to use it.

Comment: I have removed the MainMenu. 1. Right-clicking the title bar to get the system menu: This does not work but can be retrofitted. 2. Alt+Space: I can live with that. 3. "Just pressing the Alt key (or F10) causes a stack overflow + access violation + app crash": Could not reproduce that. 4. "doubleclick maximizes/restores window": Does work here. 5. "doubleclick on icon closes window": Does work here. So with the help of @AndreasRejbrand I solved all problems by removing the MainMenu. Thank you, Andreas.

Comment: @user1580348: Just don't be surprised if you find more bugs related to the custom title bar in the future. For instance, does it work well with Windows 11? IIRC, there is at least one bug: The new thing that pops up when you hover the maximize button is lost.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "The new thing that pops up when you hover the maximize button is lost." - I am not sure what you mean. I don't have Windows 11. I don't need round corners.

Comment: I am still using Windows 7, so I don't know much about Windows 11 either. But [apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu), in Windows 11, if you hover the maximize button, a window appears that let you arrange the windows on your desktop in a grid layout. I *think* that this feature is lost if you use a custom title bar. It is likely quite a few of your customers will miss that one eventually.

Comment: The broader issue is that you aren't really supposed to mess with the non-client area in strange ways. Although it is possible, you do it on your own risk, and you cannot blame Microsoft if it fails utterly on Windows 12 in the future! Just saying! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you for your thoughts. I promise I will not use `TTitleBarPanel` on every application I create. This was just an experiment to see what's possible.

Comment: I would like to know more about the PEOPLE who created components like `TTitleBarPanel`. Or is there an AI behind all this?

Comment: There is a very informative video by *Ray Konopka* about implementing custom titlebars: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIt6VPNjfwk&ab_channel=EmbarcaderoTechnologies He also explains why `TTitleBarPanel` is incompatible with `TMainMenu`: Both are using the non-client area of the form.